# Join Leads with a Custom Object based on email address

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I have been tasked to create a report that ties leads to a Custom Object(Product_Ordered).
Each object may or may not have an email on the record.
For example:
There 3 lead records with an email address of noname@test.com
There is a Product_Ordered record with the email address noname@test.com
I need to be able to show that the 3 Leads are associated to the Product_Ordered

The Lead and Product_Ordered object are currently not related.
So I tried to create a junction object but you cannot create a Master-Detailed relationship for a Lead object so I did not pursue that route.
I then tried creating a Report Type to ties the and that did  not return any results.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
M

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and make a look up to both Lead and Product Ordered objects and make those lookup fields as mandatory.

That way, if 1 Product Ordered records have 3 leads then 3 records will be created in that object.

Product_Order_1 | Lead1

Product_Order_1 | Lead2

Product_Order_1 | Lead3

Create a summary report to display the report data on this object group by Product Ordered.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  Will these suggestions work for existing records since there currently is not a relationship between the 2 objects?

Comment: You need to migrate the data for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a lookup relationship from Lead to Product Ordered. 
Then all you need to do is to relate the Product Order to the Lead. It is a one to many relationships in which the Product Ordered is the **One** and the Lead the **Many**.

If you want to automate the process you can use a trigger to related the Leads to the Product Ordered based on the email field.