# Trying to Add existing record to a Custom Object

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to add an existing Lead record(s) since there can be more than 1 to a Custom object but my code is doing it backwards.  It's adding the Custom Object to the Lead.

```
trigger Warranty_Add_Leads on Warranties_and_Surveys__c (before update) {

    Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();
    for(Warranties_and_Surveys__c was :trigger.new){
    emails.add(was.Contact_Email__c );
    }
    emails.remove(null);

    List<Lead> Leads = new List<Lead>([SELECT Account_Type__c,Email,Id,Name FROM     
    Lead WHERE Email IN :emails AND RecordTypeId='012j0000000gcNp'AND    
    Account_Type__c='Web Application']);   

    List<Warranties_and_Surveys__c> warranty = new List<Warranties_and_Surveys__c>([select id, Contact_Email__c from Warranties_and_Surveys__c where Contact_Email__c != '' AND Registration_Status__c = 'Registered' ]);
    List<Lead> lstWarranties = new List<Lead>(); 


    for(Warranties_and_Surveys__c WTY : Trigger.new)
    {
     for (Lead LL : Leads) 
    {
        if(LL.email == WTY.Contact_Email__c) 
      {  
          WTY.Leads__c = LL.id;
          lstWarranties.add(ll);
      }
    }

}
    if (lstWarranties.size()>0)
   update lstWarranties ;

}
```

So I thought all I had to do is change

```
List<Lead> lstWarranties = new List<Lead>();
```

to

```
List<Warranties_and_Surveys__c> lstWarranties = new List<Warranties_and_Surveys__c>();
```

Well that does not work either.

error : Incompatible element type Lead for collection of Warranties_and_Surveys__c

Will the code in its current state be add the same Lead record multiple times to the Warranty record

I have performed this action(relate an existing record) in a different trigger but using the same logic is not working this time around.

Thanks,
M

Comment: How you have designed this where your custom object has multiple leads? Secondly, using hard coded id is bad practice

Comment: Santanu, The Custom Object can have multiple Leads.  I can remove the Id field.  We have 300K+ Leads and I was trying to minimize the List.

Comment: This could be an issue of having the relationship field on the wrong object, or it could be that you need to use a junction object. To give an appropriate answer, we'll also need to know if you want a single `Lead` to be able to be related to more than one warranty, or if you want a single `Lead` to be related to _at most, one warranty_.

Comment: Derek, I have a Lead lookup on the Warranty object and a Warranty lookup on the  Lead object.  Should I remove the Warranty lookup on the Lead object since I need the Leads to be associated to a Warranty?  Theoretically there should only be a single Warranty per email address.  So a Lead(s)) should  only  be associated to a single warranty?  Did I answer what you are asking?  Thanks, M

Comment: Did you follow your last question where I have given this ans. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160539/join-leads-with-a-custom-object-based-on-email-address/160548#160548

Comment: Hello Santanu,  I did look at your suggestion but you are suggesting that I make the lookups mandatory which they cannot be.  Not all Leads will end in an order and not all Orders will have had a Lead.  That is what I did not go that route.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question sounds like it's about data modeling almost as much as it is about relationships. I feel that it's important to have an understanding of both. If you don't understand both, then you'll probably just be making random guesses on which sObjects to put a lookup field on, or which object should be the Master and which should be the Detail.

### Data modeling crash course

To me, data modeling is about taking a description of a system (e.g. 'we want to build something that lets dog owners see how many walks they're taking with their dog'), and turning it into a set of database tables (sObjects in our case) or classes.

For the dog walking example, the sObjects involved could be `User` (to represent the owners), `Dog__c`, and `Walks__c` (we could use `Task`, but relating a task to more than one thing could be painful).

The data model that you create will end up putting constraints on the system that is built on top of it. Using our dog walking example, if your data model includes a 1-to-1 (the short notation for that is 1:1) relationship between owners and dogs, then you're saying that a dog has a single owner, and an owner has a single dog.

It wouldn't be impossible to build a system on top of such a data model to allow an owner to have more than one dog. That said, the data model above is ill suited to handle that case. Building a system that allows an owner to have more than one dog would harder than it needs to be (and you'd likely end up duplicating owner data).

A better fitting data model for handling situations where an owner can have more than one dog is to have a one-to-many (1:n) relationship between owners and dogs.

If an owner can have any number of dogs, and a dog can have any number of owners (say you have a spouse and a child that 'own' the dog as well), then we'd need a many-to-many (n:n) relationship.

### Relationships in Salesforce

In data modeling terms, Salesforce only has one type of relationship, 1:n. Master-detail relationships, Lookup relationships, external Ids, they all create 1:n relationships.

The object that the relationship field appears on is always on the 'n' side of the 1:n relationship. For example, the Master-Detail relationship between `Opportunity` and `OpportunityLineItem` places the actual relationship field (`OpportunityId`) on the `OpportunityLineItem`. One `Opportunity` is related to many `OpportunityLineItem` records. The converse, that many `OpportunityLineItem` records can have a single `Opportunity` is equally true (just a change in perspective).

1:1 relationships are hard to do in Salesforce (only way I can think of accomplishing this is with a trigger and a query). I find it best to just treat this as something Salesforce can't do.

n:n relationships in Salesforce are possible, but can't be directly created (all relationships that we create are 1:n, after all). Creating an n:n relationship in Salesforce requires what's called a 'junction object'. A third, completely separate sObject that has either two lookup relationships, or two Master-Detail relationships.

An example of a data model with an n:n relationship would be

`User (1) --- (n) Pet (n) --- (1) Dog`

It doesn't really look like an n:n relationship at first glance, but it does end up having the properties of an n:n relationship. Trying to clearly represent such a relationship with text alone would be hard, and I don't have the time to make an image of it.

### One last note on Salesforce relationships

The related list, the thing on page layouts that displays the records that are related to the record you are currently viewing, always appears on the object that is the '1' side of a 1:n relationship.

For `Opportunity` and `OpportunityLineItem`, the `Opportunity` is the '1' side of the relationship, and `OpportunityLineItem` is the 'n' side of the relationship. Therefore, the related list will be on `Opportunity` and show all of the `OpportunityLineItems` that are related to it.

### Now, we can get to addressing your issue

You haven't been too terribly clear or detailed about what exactly it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Where my answer goes from here is mostly based on the following part of your question

> there can be more than 1 to a Custom object but my code is doing it backwards. It's adding the Custom Object to the Lead.

What I take from this is that you currently see a 'Warranties' related list on the `Lead`, but would like it the other way around (that is, seeing a `Leads` related list on a `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` record).

Following from what I said regarding relationships in Salesforce, this would require that you create a lookup field to `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` on `Lead`  (which from the comments on your question, you already have).

Assuming that you still want your trigger to be on `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` when the warranty/survey is updated, your trigger should be `after update`, because you'll be updating something that isn't a `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` record on an update to a warranty/survey (you'd use a 'before' trigger if you were making some changes to the warranty/survey itself, which you won't be doing in this case).

```
// Nothing in your trigger is changed before this point

// The results of this query aren't being used, so this query should be removed.
//List<Warranties_and_Surveys__c> warranty = new List<Warranties_and_Surveys__c>([select id, Contact_Email__c from Warranties_and_Surveys__c where Contact_Email__c != '' AND Registration_Status__c = 'Registered' ]);

// Basically, you just need to set the lookup field on a Lead to the Id of a
//   warranty (instead of the other way around).
// Since you haven't provided the name of this lookup field, I'll assume it's
//   'warranty__c'

for(Warranty_and_Survey__c warranty :trigger.new){
    for(Lead currentLead :Leads){
         if(currentLead.Email = warranty.Contact_Email__c){
            currentLead.Warranty__c = warranty.Id;
         }
    }
}

update Leads;

// end of trigger
```

While putting the fragment above into your trigger should accomplish what you want, I still have concerns.

Nested loops that iterate over two collections (i.e. a `Set`, a `List`, or a `Map`) and compare a field on one to a field on another are a red flag to me.

Nested loops like that can easily be performance killers. However, the much more important thing to address is *what happens if you have two `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` records that have the same contact email?*

This is the reason why I went into some basics of data modeling at the beginning of my answer. Having a 1:n relationship between `Lead` and `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` means that *your trigger **will** lose data if you have more than one `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` record with the same email*. Your `Lead` will be related to a `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` record, but you will *not be able to predict which one*.

If you want to put a constraint on your system so that the situation I've described above is a physical impossibility, then you'll need to make the `Contact_Email__c` field on `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` unique.

If you do this, then we can improve your trigger a bit. In this scenario, we're guaranteed that a given email will only appear, at most, on one `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` record. Thus, we can build a map where the key is the warranty contact email, and the value is the Id of the warranty record.

Doing so will allow you to take your nested loop, and turn it into a single loop instead.

```
// Declare the map that will store an email - id pair.
Map<String, Id> emailsToWarrantyId = new Map<String, Id>();

Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();

// You're already looping over warranties and surveys, so we can simply build on 
//   this loop instead of making an entirely new loop
for(Warranties_and_Surveys__c was :trigger.new){
    emails.add(was.Contact_Email__c);

    emailsToWarrantyId.put(was.Contact_Email__c, was.Id);
}

emails.remove(null);

// It's not going to be used in a query, so we don't need to remove nulls from the map.
// However, if you wanted to do so, it would look like this
//emailsToWarrantyId.keySet().remove(null);

/*
    <Existing query for Leads remains unchanged>
*/

// Now, instead of needing to have a nested loop and wasting time making a 
//   whole bunch of email comparisons that end up being unequal, we can
//   use a single loop and get the correct warranty id from the map that we
//   made earlier.
for(Lead currentLead :Leads){
    currentLead.Warranty__c = emailsToWarrantyId.get(currentLead.Email);
}

// DML update to leads remains the same
```

It should be noted that this does assume that you don't have duplicate `Leads`. Having duplciate leads here isn't nearly as problematic as having multiple `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` records, but still something to be mindful of.

If you think that you can possibly have more than one `Warranties_and_Surveys__c` record with a given email (say your customer makes multiple purchases from you, perhaps one using a desktop and another using a mobile phone) you'll need to change your data model to include a junction object so that you can handle the possible n:n relationship.

Your trigger would need to change yet again in this situation, but my answer is way too long as it is. If you'd like to ask about your data model, I'd encourage you to make another question for it. Beyond that, I hope that I've given you enough information and insight for you to make a reasonable attempt at modifying your trigger yourself to fit this situation.

Comment: Derek, Thank you very much for the informative summary. By biggest hurdles is that I inherited an existing data model and 2. poor planning.  This request would have been less complicated if we would have put some additional time and thought into how are we planning to use the data we are inserting into our SF org......Thanks for your time and patience.  M

Comment: And yes we will have multiple Leads with the same email address.  Again I would have had a single lead which housed a single email address with multiple activities but this is what I have and I need to figure out the best way to work it.  M